# Convergence to Nash Equilibria

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

I have two utility functions, $u_1(c,s)$ and $u_2(c,s)$. They are derivable. $u_1(c,s)$ refers to Player 1, while $u_2(c,s)$ to Player 2. The strategic leverage of Player 1 is $s$ while the strategic leverage of Player 2 is $c$.

In order to obtain the best response functions and Nash equilibria, I have to solve the system of the following two equations:
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial s}u_1(c,s)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial c}u_2(c,s)=0$$
From this I obtain both best response functions, i.e.
$$s=f_1(c)$$
$$c=f_1(s)$$
If I plot them in a (c,s)-plane, or solve the above system, I obtain two Nash equilibria.

Now, I'm not an expert in game theory, so please apologize if the question may seem naive or denote a lack of knowledge of the theory.

I would like to know if the game converges to these equilibria, or if it converges to only one of them. I do not know if in this game, from where I was standing, it is possible to ask a similar question or it lacks something in the definition of the model. Example, textbook and other are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, you would usually write the variable of the first player first ($u(s,c)$). Second - what kind of convergence? Are you talking about best response dynamics? From which point? In general, the answer is no. Think of Rock-Paper-Scissors. If we both play rock, then in the next step we'll both play paper and so on. At no point, we will start playing the mixed third-third-third (because best response is always pure).

Comment: @YJT thank you. That's the point. I don't know a whole lot about game theory. So I wonder what kind of convergence I could take into account and investigate, in general, to answer my question. This, for me, could be a good starting point for understanding the problem. Thank you also for your example (rock-paper-scissors), it is very clear.

Comment: It seems that you are interested in best-response dynamics, so I would start reading about it, but I'm not sure what exactly is your question and what you are trying to achieve in this problem.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll start to read best response dynamics